# How can SO(3) have 1D (scalar) representations?

Tags: group-theory

I read in Introduction to elementary particles - David Griffiths that "scalars belong to the 1D representation of the rotation group SO(3)". 
How can a scalar describe rotations in three dimensions? Or is there something I missunderstood from that statement?

Comment: They don't. Scalars describe quantities that are invariant under rotations. (I.e. transform as scalars, not vectors or tensors or spinors.)

Comment: The only 1D representation is the trivial one .